# Is it possible to make the motherboard log instant random shutdowns?

Tags: motherboard, shutdown, event-log

My computer randomly shuts down instantly. It even happens sometimes in the bios. And sometimes it runs for days under load without any problem.

I checked and it is not a temperature issue.

What I'm wondering is if it's somehow possible to log what caused the instant shutdown. I was thinking that only the motherboard could log it since sometimes it even happens when in the bios.

My motherboard is an [Asus p8p67 pro rev 3.1](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8P67_PRO_REV_31/).

Comment: The BIOS is unable to log something like this.  It sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: @Ramhound, some motherboards have a limited amount of space with which [to log](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19591-01/E23169/figures/BIOS_X4270_view_event_log.jpg) [certain events](http://www.ninjalane.com/images/sl-915gpro-fgr/bios_eventlog.jpg). Unfortunately this is not one of them. If it did, it may help since the problem is obviously hardware related.

Comment: @Synetech - All those events happened outside of the operating system.  Once you boot into the operating system anything that will be logged would be logged by the operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes I know, and Monster clearly said that the problem happens while in the BIOS as well, so it’s *not* a software issue.

Answer (score 3):

The motherboard will not keep logs like this.

This sort of failure could be caused by RAM though.
Run memtest from http://www.memtest.org/ overnight and see if it throws up errors.

The other thing it's likely to be is a power supply on its way out, but this is harder to test without installing a spare.

Outside of that, you could see if there's an updated BIOS you could flash.

Comment: thanks for answer but i am looking for motherboard level solution. because only it can help me

Comment: I'm afraid what you're trying to do cannot be done, at least not on a consumer grade motherboard.

Comment: well that definitely sucks. putting 10 mb memory for logging error text would not hurt the manufactures

Comment: I completely agree and think this would be a great idea for the future, but alas not this time!